# New Seagate GoFlex external hard drive reporting temperature 50C and higher--defective or normal?

Tags: external-hard-drive, temperature

I have a brand-new Seagate GoFlex hard drive, and my SMART diagnostics program (CrystalDiskInfo) is warnings me that the drive is running too hot.

The lowest reported temperature I've seen it is 48C, and the highest so far is 56C (all of last week, it was at 50C).  According to several sources I've found online, including a Google study, hard disks operating higher than 40C have shorter lifespans.

The temperature in the room is usually about 23C (74F), and orienting the drive vertically vs. horizontally doesn't seem to affect the operating temperature.

Does anyone else have a GoFlex external desktop drive that runs at 40C or cooler?  Is my drive just defective, or is this high temperature common for these drives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Seagate Knowledge Base article What is the normal operating temperature for Seagate disk drives? [[193771]](https://seagate.custkb.com/seagate/crm/selfservice/portalhome.jsp?DocId=193771&Hilite=)

> The operating temperature range for most Seagate hard drives is **5 to
>   50 degrees Celsius**
>
> With our newer model drives the maximum temperature is now at **60
>   degrees Celsius.**

This is simimlar for the [Western Digital Caviar Green](http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/SpecSheet/ENG/2879-701229.pdf) drives which have a recommended operating temperature of 0-60 degrees Celsius.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still a little skeptical, given that other references recommend 40C or cooler, and this drive is operating within the very upper limits of Seagate's recommended temperature ranges for *newer model drives*. It almost seems as though the drive manufacturers are intentionally designing drives to run hotter so they can sell more drives (because they are likely to fail sooner).

Comment: Just an update - a couple weeks ago, my SMART diagnostics suddenly reported 900+ reallocated sectors. As I was almost finished copying data off the drive, it reported that the reallocated sector count had reverted to 0 (which, as I understand it, is not supposed to be allowed).  I contacted Seagate and they agreed to replace the drive under warranty. Although I can't prove that the high operating temperature was responsible, the fact that this drive barely lasted 4 months has me suspicious. I guess we'll see how well the replacement drives hold up.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 GoFlex external drives and they are constantly around 47C - 49C. I have had them for about 12 months. Hope this adds some comfort.